# How can Identify Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager Traffic?

Tags: windows-server-2003, http

I'm establishing some rules for filtering my traffic based on HTTP request.  In the process I noticed some packets with the http method `CCM_POST`.  A quick search turned up [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/167026) on Server Fault and thus lead me to the Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager.

Is there anyway I can prevent my filter from capturing this traffic?  It would seem to me this would be as easy as ignoring all http methods with `CCM` in them but I can't find any definitions of the associated protocol to ensure this is the case.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? What program are you configuring the rules in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to capture the packets?

Using wireshark you could filter this traffic from the display using:

```
!(http.request.method == "CCM_POST")
```

However to prevent it's capture completely you would need to filter is based on the destination IP port of the message. The CCM_POST is sent to System Center Configuration Manager or System Management Server Management Points.

Comment: I realize I had forgotten about this question. Since I was using tshark (a cli version of wireshark) this is ultimately what I did.  I think What I was looking for was: "Does all CCM have an http method with the string 'CCM'" in it.  Turns out the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows network monitor tool that comes with Windows. Its so simple and easy.